# Mostrar posicion 0 de una variable de sesion que contiene un array

Tags: php, html

tengo una variable de sesión que se llama `$_session["arrayImagenHecha"] = $arrayImagenHecha`. Esta variable contiene un array con imágenes, mi problema es que cuando quiero hacer un echo para mostrar la posición 0 del arrya me salta un error. Por ejemplo:

```
   $arrayImagenHecha = completarImagen($array_nombres_imagenes_ordenados,$array_caracteristicas_completas_img);


shuffle($arrayImagenHecha);



$arrayImagenHecha=$_SESSION["arrayImagenHecha"];

echo "<h4 align='center'>Carta del Servidor</h4>";

echo "<table style='border:2px solid black' align='center'";

echo "<tr><td style='border:1px solid black'>
<div class='container_servidor'>
 <div id = 'servCard'class='card' >
    <div class='front'>
          <img class='img' src='assets/reverso/cardBack.jpg'/>
    </div>
    <div class='back'>
        $arrayImagenHecha[0];

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</td></tr>";



echo "</table>";
```

Este código me genera una table con varios divs y dentro muestro la posición 0 del array `$arrayImagenHecha[0]`. Quiero hacer lo mismo pero en vez de poner  `$arrayImagenHecha[0]` quiero hacer esto: `$_session["arrayImagenHecha"][0]`

Comment: Por favor muestra el resultado de `var_dump($_session);` para ver la constitución de los datos y poder ayudarte. Gracias.

Comment: Sí, me aparece esto:array(1) { ["arrayImagenHecha"]=> array(12) { [0]=> string(87) "" [1]=> string(87) "" [2]=> string(89) "" [3]=> string(85) "" [4]=> string(85) "" [5]=> string(84) "" [6]=> string(89) "" [7]=> string(89) "" [8]=> string(84) "" [9]=> string(88) "" [10]=> string(85) "" [11]=> string(85) "" } }

Todo eso seguido de cada imagen que hay en el array, que no puedo mostrar desde aquí.

Comment: Esta línea: `$arrayImagenHecha=$_SESSION["arrayImagenHecha"];` debe estar antes de que llames a `completarImagen`, la creas después, cuando la variable todavía no existe. La variable se crea y se llena con los datos de la sesión cuando haces esto:  `$arrayImagenHecha=$_SESSION["arrayImagenHecha"];` por tanto eso debe estar de primero.

Comment: Mmmm, pues no sé la verdad, me sigue dando "Undefined index: arrayImagenHecha"

Comment: Yo no termino de entender tu código. Por ejemplo esto invalida lo que haces antes que es poner en una variable los datos de la variable de sesión: `$arrayImagenHecha =completarImagen($array_nombres_imagenes_ordenados,$array_caracteristicas_completas_img);` Ahi la variable `$arrayImagenHecha` será igual al resultado de esa función. ¿Qué hace esa función? ¿las dos variables que le pasas en parámetro existen en el contexto? Propongo que pongas el script completo para revisarlo y que expliques un poco lo que quieres porque es demasiado confuso tu código.

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres poner lo que hay en `$arrayImagenHecha` en la variable de sesión, sólo tienes que hacer lo siguiente:

```
$_SESSION["arrayImagenHecha"]=$arrayImagenHecha;
```

Eso hará que tu variable de sesión tenga una nueva clave llamada `arrayImagenHecha` donde se encontrará el array. Pero asegúrate que esa clave no exista ya con otros datos en la variable de sesión, porque los sobre-escribirías.

Luego, para encontrar el primer elemento del array puedes hacer:

```
echo $_SESSION["arrayImagenHecha"][0];
```

Y si estás en el contexto en que se creó `$arrayImagenHecha`, puedes usar esa misma variable:

```
echo $arrayImagenHecha[0];
```

Para concatenarlo en tus datos, sólo tienes que hacer lo siguiente:

```
echo "<h4 align='center'>Carta del Servidor</h4>";

echo "<table style='border:2px solid black' align='center'";

echo "<tr><td style='border:1px solid black'>
<div class='container_servidor'>
 <div id = 'servCard'class='card' >
    <div class='front'>
          <img class='img' src='assets/reverso/cardBack.jpg'/>
    </div>
    <div class='back'>".$arrayImagenHecha[0]."</div>
  </div>
</div>
</td></tr>";

//resto del código
```

Comment: Pero si lo pongo como me dices me salta este error:
Undefined variable: _session. ¿ Tengo que declarar alguna variable entes de todo esto ?

Comment: ¿Acaso la variable de sesión no está disponible en ese contexto? Si no pertenece a ese contexto, ¿la recibes en parámetro?  ¿Si intentas directamente tampoco funciona: `$_SESSION["arrayImagenHecha"][0]`? Pon `$_SESSION` todo en mayúscula por si acaso.

Comment: Creo que si que pertenece, cuando tengo que declarar $arrayImagenHecha=$_SESSION["arrayImagenHecha"];
? Al principio de mi documento o justo despues de declarar la variable $arrayImagenHecha ? Ponga como lo ponga me salta error.

Comment: Cuando haces esto: `$arrayImagenHecha=$_SESSION["arrayImagenHecha"];` ya estás declarando la variable `$arrayImagenHecha` y estás diciendo que su valor es igual a lo que haya en `$_SESSION["arrayImagenHecha"]`. Debes declarar antes de usar `$arrayImagenHecha` y en un contexto donde exista `$_SESSION`. Si luego de la declaración llamas a otra función, debes pasarle a esa función la variable para que la misma se encuentre en el contexto de esa función. Si no te funciona edita la pregunta, poniendo el código como lo tienes, indicando también tu variable de sesión.

Comment: Es decir, yo tengo un array ($arrayImagenHecha), como le asigno una variable de sesión ? Así ?: $_sesion["array"] = $arrayImagenHecha

Comment: No @Marc. Está claramente explicado en la respuesta. Tienes que hacer justo lo contrario:  **`$arrayImagenHecha=$_sesion["array"]`**. Haciendo lo contrario lo que haces es anular el contenido de la variable de sesión.

Comment: He actualizado el código, me salta este error: " Notice: Undefined index: arrayImagenHecha in "

Comment: @Marc no entiendo tu código a pesar de la edición. ¿Donde está la variable de sesión?  ¿Qué significan las dos primeras líneas de ese código, qué intentas hacer con ellas?

Comment: Las dos primeras lineas son para crear las imágenes y mezclaras, la variable de sesión es: $arrayImagenHecha=$_SESSION["arrayImagenHecha"];
Mas arriba tengo el session_start().

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85202/discussion-between-a-cedano-and-marc).